# google cloud individual billing account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am unable to select google cloud individual billing account when trying to enable billing on mine google cloud account. Can't select that option and have Individual profile set for Play developer.

I am not an citizen of EU country (saw on some threads that this could be the cause).

I need this account for development purposes (Google maps API to be more exact).

[image]

Comment: Have you used Google Cloud Free Trial before? Does your account associated with some organization?

Comment: I was able to reopen billing account. Issue was that mine payment method (credit card) has been expired. Thanks to Google support.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage your Google Cloud resources using an Organization node, and you are a member of that Google Cloud Organization, then you must be a Billing Account Creator to create a new Cloud Billing account.

Specifically, if you are a Google Cloud user within an Organization, to perform this task, you must have the following permission.

**billing.accounts.create**

If you are not a member of a Google Cloud Organization but instead are managing your Google Cloud resources or Google Maps Platform APIs using projects, you do not need any specific role or permission to create a Cloud Billing account.